# How to improve multiple case when query performance?

Tags: query-performance, optimization, mariadb, query, pivot

I have the following query which counts when the event_time is equal to the day of the month.

I also have indexes on the id of each table, template_name, from_email_address, event_time, event_status.

Is there any more way I can optimise it?

I am running this against a database of at least 30 million records and this query will likely scan through at least 3 million records. I also have to run this query multiple times for different from_email_addresses.

Edited to include the explain query result.

```
select_type        tbl type   possible_keys                   key         

PRIMARY            e   ref    PRIMARY, IDX_FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS IDX_FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS 
PRIMARY            d   eq_ref PRIMARY                         PRIMARY
PRIMARY            s   ref    PRIMARY, IDX_EVENT_TIME         PRIMARY
DEPENDENT SUBQUERY ms  ref    PRIMARY, IDX_EVENT_STATUS       IDX_EVENT_STATUS
ref        rows       Extra
const      3,012,345  Using where, Using index, Using temporary, Using filesort
e.id       1
e.id,func  1          Using where; Using index
const,d.id 1          Using where; Using index
```

```
    SELECT
     d.template_name, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 1 THEN 1 END) AS '1',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 2 THEN 1 END) AS '2',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 3 THEN 1 END) AS '3',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 4 THEN 1 END) AS '4',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 5 THEN 1 END) AS '5',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 6 THEN 1 END) AS '6',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 7 THEN 1 END) AS '7',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 8 THEN 1 END) AS '8',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 9 THEN 1 END) AS '9',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 10 THEN 1 END) AS '10',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 11 THEN 1 END) AS '11',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 12 THEN 1 END) AS '12',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 13 THEN 1 END) AS '13',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 14 THEN 1 END) AS '14',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 15 THEN 1 END) AS '15',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 16 THEN 1 END) AS '16',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 17 THEN 1 END) AS '17',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 18 THEN 1 END) AS '18',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 19 THEN 1 END) AS '19',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 20 THEN 1 END) AS '20',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 21 THEN 1 END) AS '21',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 22 THEN 1 END) AS '22',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 23 THEN 1 END) AS '23',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 24 THEN 1 END) AS '24',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 25 THEN 1 END) AS '25',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 26 THEN 1 END) AS '26',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 27 THEN 1 END) AS '27',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 28 THEN 1 END) AS '28',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 29 THEN 1 END) AS '29',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 30 THEN 1 END) AS '30',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 31 THEN 1 END) AS '31',
     COUNT(*) AS 'Grand Total' 
FROM 
  detail d 
LEFT JOIN 
    email e on d.id = e.id 
LEFT JOIN 
    status s on s.id = d.id 
 AND s.event_time = (
                        SELECT
                          MINE(ms.event_time) 
                        FROM
                          status ms 
                        WEHRE 
                          ms.id = d.id 
                        AND 
                            ms.event_status = 'SENT'
                    ) 
WHERE
    CASET(s.event_time AS DATE) BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-03-31' 
 AND
    e.from_email_address = 'abc@google.com' 
GROUP BY
  d.template_name
```

Comment: could you please add table definitions and output of explain command for your query?

Comment: edited to include the explain result, also the rows scanned is more than the total count. can it be improved?

Comment: we need create table statements too

Comment: the id is varchar(36), event_time is datetime, the rest is varchar as well

Comment: as I said we need create statements, we need to see indexes and constraints, also data sample would be useful too

Comment: please check this link - https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A "better" way:**

Step 1.  Build an intermediate table:

```
SELECT
        d.template_name, 
        DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) AS dom,
        COUNT(*) AS 'Grand Total' 
    FROM ...
    GROUP BY d.template_name, dom
```

Step 2.  Pivot.  (Since this is thoroughly discussed in other Q&A, I simply added the `[pivot]` tag; go see.)

**More concise**, though maybe not any faster than the `CASE(...31...)`

```
SUM(DAYOFMONTH(s.event_time) = 31)
```

**Faster**

Build and maintain a Summary table.  Rather than rescanning millions of rows when you want this 'report', scan a much smaller and possibly better-indexed summary table.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Such a table might effectively be the result of my "Step 1", above.  However, it would be augmented daily (or continually), not rebuilt.

Answer (score 1):

this condition prevents database server from using index seek:

```
cast(s.event_time as date) between '2020-03-01'
```

first you need to change it to:

```
s.event_time >= '2020-03-01' AND s.event_time < '2020-04-01'
```

Comment: I assume cast is the problem here, not between?

Comment: @Lennart, yes, sure. But probably there are some other issues exist which we could try to fix if author could provide more details about the database.

Comment: I agree. Just wanted to clarify which of the two changes that has most impact on performance.

Comment: thanks for your response, but this doesn't help improve the query time.